# Получение первого слова из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю *python*, есть задачка - получить первое слово из строки.
Строка может начинаться с пробелов, точек и т.д (`".... пример, строки "`). Нужна функция, которая вернет слово `"пример"`.  Мой код в котором **получилось** получить слово, **но избавиться** от запятой не получается :

```
def splitText(string: str):
splitted = string.split()
for x in range(len(splitted)):
    if splitted[x].isalpha():
        print(splitted[x])
        break
```

---

```
splitText("Hello world")
```

выведет `"Hello"`, но если строка будет вида `"Hello, world"`, то выведет `"world"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таком подходе будут найдены все слова:

```
>>> import re
>>> word = '.... пример, строки'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
>>> pattern.findall(word)[0]
'пример'
```

В таком, только первое совпадение:

```
>>> pattern.search(word).group()
'пример'
```

Пример без регулярок:

```
>>> for i in word:
...     if not i.isalpha() and i != ' ':
...             word = word.replace(i, '')
...
>>> word
' пример строки'
>>> word.split()[0].strip()
'пример'
```

Comment: Спасибо, до регулярок еще не дошел!

Comment: @BoBo добавил пример без регулярок

Comment: и как ваш пример без регулярок справится с текстом типа ",п.р.и.м.е!р  строки"   =D?   родит слово которого не было из частокола точек и букв?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ну, под пример автора подходит, а работает - не трогай :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно проще:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

text = '.... пример, строки'
first_word = re.findall(r'\w+', text)[0]
```

это подходит для коротких текстов. Для больших текстов, чтобы искать только *первое* слово вместо всех сразу:

```
first_word = next(m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'\w+', text))
```

Без регулярных выражений, itertools алгоритмов, итд это можно выразить как:

```
def first_word(text):
    it = iter(text)
    for char in it:
        if char.isalnum():  # found first char
            word = [char]
            for char in it: # start with second char
                if char.isalnum():
                    word.append(char)
                else:
                    break
            return ''.join(word)
    raise ValueError("no words")
```

Пример:

```
>>> first_word('.... пример, строки')
'пример'
```

Код пользуется тем что итераторы в Питоне являются однопроходными, поэтому второй цикл `for char in it` начинает со второго символа в слове (где предыдущий цикл остановился). Просто `for char in text` начинает каждый раз с начала  с первого символа, если text это последовательность (строка в данном случае).

Answer (score 0):

```
first_word = lambda text: text.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').strip().split(' ')[0]
```

Этот вариант сработает на тексте "Don't eat it". А приведенные выше решения - нет )))

Comment: Ничто не мешает добавить в регулярное выражение обработку апострофа: `r"[\w']+"`. В вашем варианте, кстати, не учитывается что если второе отделено от первого просто запятой или точкой, то они сольются вместе.

Comment: @insolor  эта задача вероятнее всего взята отсюда https://py.checkio.org/
как и "мое" решение, которое прошло все тесты. Просто автор вопроса не вполне описал задачу ))

Comment: как на слова текст разбить, зависит от задачи. Можно разные задачи придумывать (к примеру, `"J.R.R. Tolkien"`). Стандартный алгоритм из nltk пакета возвращает первое слово `do` (don't воспринимается как сокращение от "do not"): `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("Don't eat it")` -> `['Do', "n't", 'eat', 'it']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# как-то так
def first_word(text: str) -> str:
    # функция ниже убирает лишние точки и запятые в слове
    def removeExtraSymbols(text: str) -> str:
        result = text.replace('.', '')
        result = result.replace(',', '')
        return result
    
    allWords = text.split() # разбиваем на слова по пробелу
    for word in allWords: # пробежимся по всем "словам" в предложении
        if not removeExtraSymbols(word) == '':  # если после удаления лишних символов у нас есть буквы
            if "." in word: # если нам подсунули Hello.World (без пробела после точки) 
                word = word.split(".")[0] # берем только первое слово перед точкой
            if "," in word: # если нам подсунули Hello,World (без пробела после запятой) 
                word = word.split(",")[0] # берем только первое слово перед запятой
            return removeExtraSymbols(word) # возвращаем слово без символов
```