# While для проверки двух условий, содержащих оператор "!="

Tags: python-3.x

Условие - Программа должна находить и выводить первое найденное слово в строке. Строка может начаться с пробела, запятой или точки (и закончиться слово может этими же символами) и потому программа должна найти, где начинается первая буква слова и заканчивается последняя. 
(Например, если строка " .,Hello,. world", вывести нужно "Hello")

Решил реализовать это путем перебора циклом while. Первый по порядку while работает нормально и находит начало слова, второй почему то выдает ошибку, хотя написал вроде бы аналогичное выражение.

Ошибка:

> while (text[i]!=' ' or text[i]!="," or text[i]!="."): 
>   IndexError:string index out of range

Как исправить эту ошибку или как  по другому можно реализовать данную программу.

```
def first_word(text: str) -> str:
    """
        returns the first word in a given text.
    """
    # your code here
    i=0
    while (text[i]==' 'or text[i]=="," or text[i]=="."):
        i += 1
    else:
        wordstart = i
        print(wordstart)

    while (text[i]!=' ' or text[i]!="," or text[i]!="."):
        i += 1
    else:
        wordfinish = i
        print(wordfinish)

    print(text[wordstart:wordfinish])

first_word(" .  Hello,, world")
```

Comment: во втором `while` должны быть `and`

Comment: напишите так: `while text[i] in [' ', ",", "."]:` и `while i < len(text) and text[i] not in [' ',",","."]:` будет понятнее

Comment: А где почитать про else с операторами цикла - не сталкивался пока ?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich не выходит - `wordstart = i` выполняется в любом случае или код неверный?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich else выполняется как последняя иттерация, когда условие не выполнилось, то есть тоже самое, что написать после цикла. Я так понимаю, нужен только если break сказать, то цикл прервется, а поскольку else часть цикла, он тоже не выполнится - https://eval.in/928857

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich вот нашел, здесь именно так и написано - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement#26541090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да просто у Вас логика нарушилась, добавляем символы к слову пока
  *и не `,` и не     и не  `.`*

```
def first_word(text: str) -> str:
    """
        returns the first word in a given text.
    """
    # your code here
    i=0
    while (text[i]==' 'or text[i]=="," or text[i]=="."):
        i += 1
    else:
        wordstart = i
        print(wordstart)


    while (text[i]!=' ' and text[i]!="," and text[i]!="."):
        i += 1
    else:
        wordfinish = i
        print(wordfinish)

    print(text[wordstart:wordfinish])

first_word(" .  Hello,, world")
```

Comment: спасибо! Наконец пришла ясность)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы разбить текст на слова, используя указанные разделители, можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('[ .,]+', " .  Hello,, world")
['', 'Hello', 'world']
```

Чтобы первое не пустое слово получить:

```
>>> next(filter(None, re.split('[ .,]+', " .  Hello,, world")))
'Hello'
```

В виде функции:

```
import re

def first_word(text, sep=re.compile(r'\W+')):
    return next(filter(None, sep.split(text)))
```

Можно также адаптировать решение из [Получение первого слова из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/747348/23044) вопроса. Обратный regex с `re.find*()` или используя явный цикл с изменённым условием:

```
def first_word(text, sep=' .,'):
    it = iter(text)
    for char in it:
        if char not in sep:
            word = [char]
            for char in it:
                if char not in sep:
                    word.append(char)
                else:
                    break
            return ''.join(word)
    raise ValueError("no words")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print(re.findall(r"[\w']+",s)[0])
```

Тут только проблема с апострофом, я типо хз "I'm" это два слово или одно, используйте то, что нужно в вашей ситуации.